# Referencing a parameter in a function directly

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit a piece of code written by a development company, which uses the following construct a lot:

```
$dbcol = grabdata($strSqlB,'','','','','','',2);
```

Is there really not an easier way to do this? The code is completely unreadable.

I would have thought that the following would work, and work well for readability:

```
$vars = array("parameter1" => $strSqlB, "parameter7" => 2);
$dbcol = grabdata($vars);
```

is there anything that needs to be refactored in the function itself to make this work? Is there anything else clever we could do to make this less of a clusterfudge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [help with passing arguments to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870917/help-with-passing-arguments-to-function)

Comment: As an alternative to the (better) solution in @Pekka's comment you could also reorder the parameters in the function so the `$strSqlB` and whatever `2` represents are first and set default values as `NULL` for the rest. Then you'd only need to call `grabdata($strSqlB, 2)` as you'd have set defaults for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to refactor this part:

```
function  grabdata($parameter1, $parameter2,$parameter3,$parameter4,$parameter5,$parameter6,$parameter7){
```

to

```
function  grabdata($vars){
extract($vars);
```

these two snippets should do exactly the same IF $vars is like you described in your question

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your params for accept null.

```
function grabdata($strSqlB , $param7 , $param1 = null , $param2 = null , ....){
   //Code
}

//Exec
$dbcol = grabdata($strSqlB , $param7);
```

Comment: Ok. next time >.<! post in english ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring would be necessary as the function would need to reference the parameter array by the appropriate key, rather than by specific parameter variable references.  Regarding what you could do to further refactor, I'd have to know more about the function itself.