# How to write a constructor that will initialize class fields without hardcoding the field names

Tags: php, constructor

How to improve my attempt:

```
class gotClass {
    protected $alpha;
    protected $beta;
    protected $gamma;
    (...)

    function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4) {
        $this->alpha = $arg1;
        $this->beta = $arg2;
        $this->gamma = $arg3;
        (...)
    }
}
```

to something nice and compact like (edited in response to comments)

```
class gotClass {
        protected $alpha;
        protected $beta;
        protected $gamma;
        (...)

    function __construct($alpha, $beta, $gamma) {
        $functionArguments = func_get_args();
        $className = get_called_class();
        $classAttributes = get_class_vars($className);
        foreach ($functionArguments as $arg => $value)
            if (array_key_exists($arg, $classAttributes))
                $this->$arg = $value;
}
```

I can't get it work, I don't know the right functions to use. Did I mention I'm new to PHP? Your help is much much appreciated.

EDIT: The field names do not conform to any pattern as the unedited post may have suggested. So their names cannot be constructed in some field[i]-like loop. My apologies for being unclear.

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `->` should be `=>` in the foreach statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Edit after comments**: PHP's lack of support for named arguments (that would fix this problem altogether) is a much-lamented thing. In my experience, as long as there is no native solution to the problem, it is indeed better to declare each parameter separately for the purposes of automatic document generation and the lookup function in your IDE. The IDE can show the expected parameters only if they are explicitly declared.
>
> See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870917/help-with-passing-arguments-to-function) for another popular workaround to the issue.

If you *need* to do this anyway, you need  [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to retrieve all arguments passed to the constuctor, and an array to map the property names.

Something like

```
private $fields = array("alpha", "beta", "gamma");

function __construct()
 { 
   $args = func_get_args();
   foreach ($args as $index => $arg)
    { $this->{($this->fields[index])} = $arg; }
 }
```

this is not doing any checks on whether the specified variable exists - maybe add some more detail about what checks you exactly need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I should have mentioned the fields have non-sequential names so "field".($index+1) won't work. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Lou how would you map the arguments to the names then?

Comment: That's what I was hoping I could do dynamically. Say if func_get_args() would not just return argument values, but also their names (as set by the constructor definition), I could just check against the classAttributes to see if a corresponding field exists and set it. However, func_get_args() only returns values, so that method won't work. I'm trying to get this to work so the __construct method can be used in any class, and also with an unlimited amount of class fields, without having to hardcode every single field name into the constructor.

Comment: @Lou hmm, in that case, you'd have to employ an array hard-coded in the object definition mapping the field name to each position. That's the only way to do that that I can think of.

Comment: As a newbie, I guess my question is if you would prefer that to hardcoding the field names in the constructor? (I'm thinking of classes with tons of fields that need to be set by the constructor)

Comment: @Lou that is a sad state of affairs in PHP, yeah. I edited my answer, adding an argument in favour of hardcoding the field names and a solution with a array mapping field names and arguments if you want to go that route anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, this

```
foreach ($args as $arg -> $value)
```

Should be

```
foreach ($args as $arg => $value)
```

In the first example you would need to call

```
new gotClass($a, $b, $c)
```

But in your second example your expecting one array as a parameter so you would need to do

```
new gotClass(array($a, $b, $c))
```

You may want to refector and use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), using this will mean the following format will still work

```
new gotClass($a, $b, $c) 

function __construct() {
    $className = get_called_class();
    $classAttributes = get_class_vars($className);
    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg -> $value)
        if (array_key_exists($arg, $classAttributes))
            $this->$arg = $value;
}
```